# CDF of a sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two independent (and identically distributed) random variables. Let $Z:=X+Y$.

It's easy to check that the *moment generating function* $\phi_Z(t):=\mathbb{E}[\,e^{itZ}\,]$ can be expressed as $\phi_Z=\phi_X\cdot\phi_Y$.

Is there a way to express the *cumulative distribution function* $F_Z(z):=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)$ using the cumulative distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ ?

Edit: note I don't assume that $X$ and $Y$ have a density.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
  F_Z \left( z \right) & = & \int F_X  \left( z - y
  \right) dF_Y \left( y \right)\\
  & = & \int F_Y  \left( z - x \right) dF_X \left( x
  \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I don't assume $X$ and $Y$ have a density, I edit the question to make it clear.
Does the second formula you wrote always hold? The integral is a Riemann-Stietjes integral?
Is it possible to generalize the formula to a sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables?

Comment: Yes, the integral is Lebesgue-Stieltjes, and it holds generally. I guess it could be generalized to $n$ variables.

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is true?

Answer (score 8):

Yes

$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = P(X+Y\leq z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}F_Y(z-x)f(x)dx.
$$

BTW, if differentiate it with respect to $z$ you obtain
$$
f_Z(z) = (f_X*f_Y)(z)
$$
where $*$ stands for convolution.

EDIT: Followed by Dilip comment, we also have the relation

$$
F_Z(z) = (F_X*f_Y)(z) = (f_X*F_Y)(z)
$$

Comment: I don't assume $X$ and $Y$ have a density, I edit the question to make this point clear.

Comment: In this case, Learner answer is what you seek for (after "This could have been written also as")..