# PDF & CDF of a Sum of Weighted Independent Random Variables $Z=aX+bY$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

From this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264116/cdf-of-a-sum-of-independent-random-variables), I learned that the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of $Z=X+Y$ is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  F_Z \left( z \right) & = & \int F_X  \left( z - y
  \right) dF_Y \left( y \right)\\
  & = & \int F_Y  \left( z - x \right) dF_X \left( x
  \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

And Probability Density Function (PDF) of $Z=X+Y$ is:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f_Z \left( z \right) & = & \int f_X  \left( z - y
  \right) f_Y \left( y \right)dy\\
  & = & \int f_Y  \left( z - x \right) f_X \left( x
  \right)dx
\end{eqnarray*}

How about PDF and CDF of sum of weighted independent random variables $Z=aX+bY$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers? I tried finding in this site but no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)&=Pr(aX+bY<z)=\int Pr(aX+by<z)f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int F_X\left(\frac{z-by}{a}\right)f_Y(y)dy\\
f_Z(z)&=\frac{1}{|a|}\int f_X\left(\frac{z-by}{a}\right)f_Y(y)dy
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! i will check them numerically soon