# Distribution function of sum of two independent variables.

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables ($X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$) with distribution functions $F$ and $G$ respectively. ($F(t) = P\{X\leq t\}$), what's the distribution function of $Z= X+Y$?

According to [statlect.com](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/sums-of-independent-random-variables#hid2) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264116/cdf-of-a-sum-of-independent-random-variables), it seems that $Z(z)=\int_{\Omega} F(z-Y) dP = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} F(z-y) d(P\circ Y^{-1}) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} F(z-y) G(dy)$, but I don't know how to prove it.

(statlect.com provides a proof, but I don't know why $P\{X\leq z-Y\}= \int_{\infty}^{\infty} P\{X\leq Z-y\}/P\{Y=y\} dy = \int_{\Omega} F(z-Y)dP$, I'm not even sure wether its notation means this.)

BTW, you could ignore what I commented and just find the distribution of $Z$. (with proof of course.)

Comment: the keyword you might want to search for is "convolution"

Comment: @MaithreyaSitaraman I don't know how to convolute things without having probability density functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to understand the idea, so i will make a (quite unnecessary) simplifying assumption that both $X$ and $Y$ are positive but i think it helps conceptually.

Then, the idea is that probability for $X+Y$ to be greater than $t$ is the infinitesimal probability that $X=s<t$ and the probability that Y is greater than $t−s$; and we must vary $s$ over all numbers up till $t$. So:

$P(X + Y > t) = \int_0^t dP(X = s)P(Y > t-s)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $H(t) = P\{Z \leq t\}$.

Then in order of $Z$ to be $ \leq t$ two things must happen:

- $X$ must be some (any) value, call it $x$.
- $Y$ must be less than $(t-x)$.

So 
$$H(t) = P\{Z \leq t\} = \int_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} \left.\frac{d F(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=x} G(t-x)\, dx$$

Which, by IBP, is the same as 
$$
\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty} \left.\frac{d G(t)}{dt}\right|_{t=y} F(t-y)\, dy$$

Comment: Why $P\{Z\leq t\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots$? Intuitively it's true, is there a rigorous argument?

Comment: Actually, it is an integral over the domain of the variable $X$.  However, taking the usual convention that the pdf is zero outside the domain of $X$, the limits can be taken to be $(-\infty,+\infty)$ without changing anything. A trickier question is why use real numbers at all? But if the notions of fully-ordered $\leq$  and of  $+$  are present, you can always model the domains as (possibly subsets of) the real line.