# CDF of $X+Y$ does not equal CDF of $X$ plus CDF of Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am studying probability theory and I am very new with the concept.

In a tutorial exercise I need to show that the following statement is **false**:

If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables defined on a probability space $(Ω, A , P)$, then $F_{X +Y}  = F_X + F_Y $.

I tried to make a counterexample, but I am not sure if I compute the CDF of $X+Y$ correctly. Can someone verify this for me?

I came up with the following:

Consider two fair dices: one dice is just a normal dice (1,2,3,4,5,6), the other one has repetitive numbers (1,1,2,2,3,3).

Now I want to show that $F_{X+Y}(3) = F_X(3) + F_Y(3)$ doesn't hold:

Note: $F_X(3) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $F_Y(3) = 1$.

Now compute $F_{X+Y}(3)$:

$F_{X+Y}(3) = \frac{1}{6}*0+\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}*\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{6}*1+\frac{1}{6}*1+\frac{1}{6}*1 = \frac{2}{3}$

Thus, since $\frac{1}{2} +1 \neq \frac{2}{3}$, we have a contradiction here.

Is the way I computed $F_{X+Y}(3)$ correct?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but you can take a shortcut here: Since $F_X(3) + F_Y(3) > 1$ and $F_{X+Y}(z) \leq 1$ for all $z$ you do not even have to compute $F_{X+Y}(3)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264116/cdf-of-a-sum-of-independent-random-variables

Comment: Instead of finding one example where $F_X+F_Y \neq F_{X+Y}$  give me one example where $F_X+F_Y = F_{X+Y}$.

Comment: And why didn't you think of $X=Y=0$ for a  counterexample. In this case you compute $F_Z$ easily, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Z = X+Y$. Now observe the following two quantities:

$$P(Z \le z) (1)$$

$$P(X \le z) + P(Y \le z) \quad (2)$$

Does $(2)$ imply $(1)$? No.

You can construct multiple counter examples without explicitly constructing a CDF. For example $X = z-1$ and $Y=z-1$. In general, the CDF for $Z$ will be calculated as follows in case $X$ and $Y$ are discrete RV:

$$F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z)$$
$$= \sum_{y}P(Z\le z|Y=y)\times P(Y=y)$$
$$=\sum_{y}P(X\le z-y)\times P(Y=y)$$
$$=\sum_{y}F_X(z-y) \times P(Y=y)$$

In case of continuous random variables, the following argument applies:

$$F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z)$$
$$= \int_{y} P(Z \le z|Y=y) \times f_Y(y) dy$$
$$=\int_{y} P(X \le z-y) \times f_Y(y) dy$$
$$=\int_{y} F_{X}(z-y) \times f_Y(y) dy$$

Comment: What is the point of such long arguments when $F_X+F_Y$ can never  be  a distribution function?

Comment: You're right sir. Your argument was short and sweet. I upvoted it for the same reason. Mine was to just tell the OP how he/she can go about calculating the CDF of the sum of the RVs.

Answer (score 3):

Sum of two distribution functions is **never** a distribution function. This is because any distribution function tends to 1at $\infty$ and $1+1\neq 1$

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a need to compute $F_{X+Y}(3)$ actually since the sum of $F_X(3)$ and $F_Y(3)$ already exceeds $1$.

\begin{align}
F_{X+Y}(3) &= Pr(X+Y=3) + Pr(X+Y=2) \\
&= Pr(X=2,Y=1)+Pr(X=1,Y=2)+ Pr(X=1,Y=1)\\
&= \frac16\cdot  \frac13 + \frac16 \cdot \frac13 + \frac16\cdot \frac13 \\
&= \frac16
\end{align}