# Convolution of uniform distributions

Tags: probability, convolution

If $X$ is a random variable with a continuous uniform distribution on (0,10), and $Y$ is also from a continuous uniform distribution on (0,10) how do I calculate the CDF of $X+Y$?

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264116/cdf-of-a-sum-of-independent-random-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can compute this directly as follows. First, for any $0<t<20$ write

$$
F(t):=\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leq t) = \int_{0}^{10} \mathbb{P}(X+y\leq t) \frac{1}{10}\, dy
$$

Case I: $20>t\geq 10$, then

$$
F(t)= \int_{0}^{10}  \frac{\min{\{t-y,10}\}}{100}\, dy = 1-\frac{(20-t)^2}{100}.
$$

Case II: $0<t<10$, then
$$
F(t)= \int_{0}^{10}  \frac{\max{\{t-y,0}\}}{100}\, dy = \frac{t^2}{200}.
$$